# Splitting nth elements in a string in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

currently I have column in a pandas dataframe. `df` that looks  like this:

| read_name |
| --- |
| NB511043:297:HJJMHBGXJ:1:22110:22730:3876 |
| NB511043:297:HJJMHBGXJ:4:22609:8139:4265 |
| NB511043:298:HT6KCBGXJ:1:13311:16766:2025 |

What I'm hoping to do is specifically extract the 5th and 7th elements of each string in this df and append these to the end of the same dataframe, like so:

| value | 5th element | 7th element |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NB511043:297:HJJMHBGXJ:1:22110:22730:3876 | 22110 | 3876 |
| NB511043:297:HJJMHBGXJ:4:22609:8139:4265 | 22609 | 4265 |
| NB511043:298:HT6KCBGXJ:1:13311:16766:2025 | 13311 | 2025 |

my current method is to create a whole new dataframe using `str.split` to split everything in read_name, and then simply append these values to the new dataframe. Like so

```
df_read_name= df['read_name'].str.split(":", n = 6, expand = True)
df['5th element']= pd.to_numeric(df_read_name[4])
df['7th element']= pd.to_numeric(df_read_name[6])
```

However, I think this is a bit cumbersome and was hoping there might be a faster approach.

as always, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Unless you're looking for a one-liner - in which case you can simply index directly after `.split` and set the two columns at once - I don't think you'll get a faster approach than this.

Comment: Thanks @Holt, I gave a quick try of everyone's code and although the regex is definitely a touch faster, as mozway pointed it's less easy to adapt. I think your one-liner might be the way to go!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.str.split` with `expand=True`:

```py
df[["5th element", "7th element"]] = df["read_name"].str.split(":", expand=True)[[4, 6]].astype(int)
```

Comment: I think this was OP's original approach they wanted to avoid ;)

Comment: @mozway Ah, right... Well, I don't think the regex approach is faster anyway (probably needs benchmark but, err, regex).

Comment: @mozway, yes. Although having tested the regex and Holt's approach I think the difference between the regex speed and mine/Holt's was very minimal, being as it's more concise than mine currently I think it might be the way to go.

Comment: @KLM117 as I said in my answer, I probably would use split as well, explicit and easy to modify ;)

Answer (score 3):

You could use `str.extract` here:

```
df[["5th element", "7th element"]] = df["value"].str.extract(r'(?:[^:]+:){4}([^:]+):[^:]+:([^:]+).*')
```

Comment: great minds think alike :p

Comment: It is funny, I saw your answer come in and thought it were Jezrael.

Answer (score 2):

If you're really always interested in the 5th and 7th element, you could use a regex with [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html), but honestly your approach is explicit and fine, **and easier to adapt**:

```
regex = r'(?:[^:]+:){4}([^:]+):[^:]+:([^:]+)'
df[['5th element', '7th element']] = df['read_name'].str.extract(regex).astype(int)
```

output:

```
                                   read_name  5th element  7th element
0  NB511043:297:HJJMHBGXJ:1:22110:22730:3876        22110         3876
1   NB511043:297:HJJMHBGXJ:4:22609:8139:4265        22609         4265
2  NB511043:298:HT6KCBGXJ:1:13311:16766:2025        13311         2025
```